# How to call function using bracket notation in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, faker

I know we can access data using dot notation and bracket notation but here if I access faker data using bracket notation I can't access that data. Is there any way to access data using bracket notation?

```
var faker = require("faker");

console.log(faker.name.findName()); // Output: any name.
console.log(faker["name.findName"]()); // Output:  TypeError: faker.name.findName is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that

```
faker["name.findName"]
```

would try to access a property called `"name.findName"` on the `faker`-object.

In order to access `findName` using bracket-notation, you need to change it to:

```
console.log(faker["name"]["findName"]());
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use bracket notation to return functions.

```
console.log(faker["name"].findName())
```

or if you really just want to use brackets, try

```
let _findName = faker["name"]["findName"];
console.log(_findName());
```